# C# Using a only a couple buttons for many different methods?

Tags: c#, button

I'm trying to make a "Choose your own adventure game" in C#, and having a problem with the buttons. I have 6 buttons, and I want to reuse them for the different options on each "page" of the story. [Program Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DtEw.png)

As an example, I was using this for btn1.

```
void page1(){
txtStory.Text = "Can you sneak past the enemy?";
    btn1.Click += (sender, args) => {
        luckCheck();
        if (lucky) {page2(); clearButtons();}
        else {page3(); clearButtons();}
    };
}

    void luckCheck(){
        int luckTest = gen.Next(1,12);
        if (luckTest <= playerLuck) {lucky = true;}
        else {lucky = false;}
    }

    void clearButtons(){
    btnN.Text = "";
    btnS.Text = "";
    btnE.Text = "";
    btnW.Text = "";
    btn1.Text = "";
    btn2.Text = "";
    btn3.Text = "";
    btn4.Text = "";
    btn5.Text = "";
    btn6.Text = "";
    }

void page2(){
txtStory.Text = "Lucky!";
}

void page3(){
txtStory.Text = "Not Lucky!";
}
```

Even though it has moved on to another method, if clicked, btn1 still repeats the same command from page1. Is there a way to stop this from happening? Like clearing the memory for the button or something.

Comment: Build a little state machine. Represent each state with an object that includes what should be shown as the text, what text should be shown on each button, and what "next state" should be associated with each button press. The button handler for each button merely has to look the the current state and see what state should be transitioned to (and then set the the current state and reset the text and the button labels from that state). Sorry, I'm on my phone, so I can't post code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without going into details as to how the code above could be structured better, here is a solution using C# 7. Note how a local function is assigned to handle the event then unassigned - using [Delegate Type Inference](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/noahc/2008/09/23/delegate-type-inference-in-c/)

```
void page1(){
    txtStory.Text = "Can you sneak past the enemy?";

    void Btn1Click(object s, EventArgs ev)
    {
        luckCheck();
        if (lucky) {page2(); clearButtons(); btn1.Click -= Btn1Click; }
        else {page3(); clearButtons();}
    };

    btn1.Click += Btn1Click;

    void luckCheck(){
    int luckTest = gen.Next(1,12);
    if (luckTest <= playerLuck) {lucky = true;}
    else {lucky = false;}
    }

    void clearButtons(){
    btnN.Text = "";
    btnS.Text = "";
    btnE.Text = "";
    btnW.Text = "";
    btn1.Text = "";
    btn2.Text = "";
    btn3.Text = "";
    btn4.Text = "";
    btn5.Text = "";
    btn6.Text = "";
    }

    void page2(){
    txtStory.Text = "Lucky!";
    }

    void page3(){
    txtStory.Text = "Not Lucky!";
    }
```

Comment: Also needs the unhook in the `else` of `Btn1Click`, or outside of the condition altogether.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're having is that `page1()` is attaching an anonymous handler method, which is never detached, so each time you call it, you are just adding more and more handlers.

But this design is going to get out of hand very quickly once you start adding lots of pages.

Consider a different design, where you have a `Page` class to represent each page. That class would have the story as a property on it, and a collection of possible `Choice`s (rather than hard-coding 6 of them). `Choice` is a class with a `Description` string property and an `Action` method to be executed if it is used.

Your application can hold the CurrentPage property, and your Choice's Action will need to be able to navigate by changing that page. Etc, etc...

Hope this helps.

P.S. extra tip. Rather than returning the result of the `luckCheck` method on a class field, consider redesigning it to return the result:

```
bool luckCheck(){
    int luckTest = gen.Next(1,12);
    return luckTest <= playerLuck;
}
```